# JQuery getJSON doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from Wikipedia via AJAX. After fiddling with the API for a while, I got to the point where my request URL actually displays what I need, which is the text from a certain section. But my AJAX request fails to return it. Here is my function:

```
function getSectionText(page, section) {
    $.getJSON(
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query', {
            prop: 'revisions',
            rvlimit: '1',
            rvsection: section,
            rvprop: 'content',
            format: 'json',
            titles: page
        },
        function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    )
}
```

This has nothing to do with origins, since I'm launching my function from a Wikipedia page, using Chrome's JS console. Yet, when I write `var someVariable = getSectionText(wgPageName, someNumber)`, and then try to call `someVariable`, Chrome says it is "undefined". Help please!

An example URL: [my sandbox, first section](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvsection=1&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=User%3ABluefire272).

Comment: Try logging your data object to the console and check what you get . console.log(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous!  You cannot return the data from `$.getJSON`.  You need to do everything related to the returned JSON inside the callback.

```
function getSectionText(page, section) {
    $.getJSON(
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query', {
            prop: 'revisions',
            rvlimit: '1',
            rvsection: section,
            rvprop: 'content',
            format: 'json',
            titles: page
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
}
```

Or, you can use the `promise` object returned, and attach a callback to that.

```
function getSectionText(page, section) {
    return $.getJSON(
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query', {
            prop: 'revisions',
            rvlimit: '1',
            rvsection: section,
            rvprop: 'content',
            format: 'json',
            titles: page
        }
    );
}

getSectionText('User:Bluefire272', 1).done(function(data){
    // You can use your data here
})
```

Comment: What does console.log() do :o

Comment: @Bluefire: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log  Use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J` to open the console (in most browsers).

Comment: What if I want to actually use that data? Is there a way I could retrieve it from the function, e.g. assign it to a variable, etc

Comment: @Bluefire: What do you want to do with it?  You can set it to a global variable, and read it when the AJAX call is done, but you still need to wait until the AJAX call is done before you can use it.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I just want to retrieve it and use it outside of the function. How would I do that?

Comment: @Bluefire: You'd still need to use a callback, you can set `window.JSONdata = data` (or something), but you'd need to make sure the AJAX call was done before you could use that.  You may need to re-think the rest of your code, as using data from an AJAX call outside its callback isn't always the right thing to do.  You want to use the callback to access the data.